# How do I get output size to stick?

Tags: output

I have increased size of text to something I can read comfortable.  When I delete output and evaluate notebook again with any changes made, the output text size returns to eyestrain inducing size.

Comment: How do you go about increasing the size of the text? (There are various ways.)

Comment: I have been using Format > Size > Larger (or pick a particular size from drop down menu) after selecting all.  The guidance I found on style sheets looked like I would need to leave a trail of bread crumbs to ever find my way back out . . .

Comment: You might use the Window > Magnification > ... menu to enlarge the overall size everything displayed in a Notebook window. I have poor vision and I normally work with at a magnification of 150%. Makes both input and output easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

This will plot out a phrase in four different sizes. The syntax for changing the size is just

```
Graphics[Style[Text["text",position],textsize]]

Table[Graphics[Style[Text["how about this?", {0, 0}], size]], {size, 
  10, 40, 10}]
```